# Activator : Play Framework 2.3.x : run vs. start

Tags: scala

Why do these two commands behave differently?

Starting Play in production mode and starting dev mode differs?

```
activator run -Dconfig.file=/myConfig.conf # works
activator "run -Dconfig.file=/myConfig.conf" # works

activator "start -Dconfig.file=/myConfig.conf" # Works
activator start -Dconfig.file=/myConfig.conf # Doesn't, config file not found
```

Comment: AFAIR these commands use different root dirs? Considering that one of them is recompiling everything if source code changes, another doesn't.

Comment: If that was the cause, then shouldn't the third command also fail ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The fundamental difference between the two commands is what is tripping you up here. The `activator` starts a JVM and then executes the command you've given on the command line. The difference between `run` and `start` is the introduction of another JVM. The `start` command starts your program in a new JVM while `run` does not. So, for your four cases:

```
activator run -Dconfig.file=/myConfig.conf # works
```

The -D argument is going to activator's JVM which then executes `run`. It works because run is using the same JVM as the activator.

```
activator "run -Dconfig.file=/myConfig.conf" # works
```

The activator's JVM gets no -D argument but it interprets "run -Dconfig.file=/myConfig.conf" and sets the config.file property accordingly, also in the activator's JVM.

```
activator "start -Dconfig.file=/myConfig.conf" # Works
```

The activator starts a new JVM and passes the -D option to it as well as starting your program, so it works because your program gets the config.file property.

```
activator start -Dconfig.file=/myConfig.conf # Doesn't work, config file not found
```

The activator's JVM receives the -D option and then executes `start` command by creating a new JVM which does not get a -D option so it fails.