# Play Framework setting user.home

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt, playframework-2.3

I'm trying to set `user.home` to another directory. When I launch the server with the following command

```
sudo -E  sbt run -Duser.home=$HOME -Dhttp.port=80
```

everything works. However when I attempt to launch the server using the `start` keyword as follows

```
sudo -E  sbt start -Duser.home=$HOME -Dhttp.port=80
```

the variable `user.home` is not changed to the current user's home directory, it is the root directory `/root`

How can I change the `user.home` variable when launching the server to production?

Comment: `sbt "start -Duser.home=$HOME -Dhttp.port=80"` ? (notice quotes)

Comment: Explain is in this [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26611298/2506303)